# Auth0 redirecting back to call url after login angular2

Tags: angular, authentication, angularjs-routing, auth0

After login the auth0 redirects me back to the call back url on angular2. How can i make it go to the path that i gave to the routing without redirecting to the call back url.

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly are you trying to do? Maybe with an example?

Comment: I have created route so if the login is success it will redirect to another page using the Authguard. but when i like enter the correct details it redirects to the particular page and comes back to localhost which i have given as a call back url in auth0 configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I've been working through this same issue.. It seems you have a couple options.

#### a) Use popup mode

This is easy to implement but Auth0 recommends to **not** use this because of browser inconsistencies. (namely some [IE and Chrome/Firefox on iOS](https://auth0.com/forum/t/popup-login-window-is-not-closed-after-authentication/2843))

It's as simple as adding a flag to your lock options object

```
var lockOptions = {
  auth: {
    redirect: false
  }
}
```

[Popup Mode Docs](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v10/popup-mode)

#### b) Save state in LocalStorage

Auth0 suggests saving state to LocalStorage if you want to allow users to resume where they left off.

So, just before triggering `lock.show()`, you could save the current URL/path/state/etc into local storage. In my case, I'm using an authGuard.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn) {
        return Promise.resolve(true);
    }

    // Store the attempted URL for redirecting after auth
    localStorage.setItem('redirectUrl', state.url);

    // Navigate to the login page
    this.router.navigate([`${environment.loggedOutRoute}`]);

    return Promise.resolve(false);
}
```

Then inside your auth callback:

```
// On authentication
this.lock.on('authenticated', (authResult: any) => {
    // Save the token in LS
    localStorage.setItem('token', authResult.idToken);

    // Hide the login modal
    this.lock.hide();

    // Redirect the user
    const redirectUrl: string = localStorage.getItem('redirectUrl');
    if (redirectUrl) {
        this.router.navigate([redirectUrl]);
    } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/overview']);
    }
});
```