# Auth0 application redirect back to original URL in Apache WebApp

Tags: apache, openid-connect, auth0

*Note: Similar questions deal with either [Auth0 with Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39199897/auth0-redirecting-back-to-call-url-after-login-angular2) or are [several years out of date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303094/forms-authentication-redirect-back-to-original-domain) and refer to previous versions.*

We're using Auth0 to provide authentication for a group of applications run on Apache with `mod_auth_openidc`.

The only customization is that `mod_auth_openidc` is configured to check whether a user has access to a specific application or not via:

```
<location /app1/>
    AuthType openid-connect
    Require claim valid_app1:true
</Location>

<location /app2/>
    AuthType openid-connect
    Require claim valid_app2:true
</Location>
```

User metadata defined in the Auth0 settings (valid_app1 or valid_app2, etc) defines whether a user can access the applications located at `website.com/app1` or `website.com/app2`, etc.

Currently, the user is **correctly redirected** to the Auth0 login page when the user tries to access any of the applications, and **correctly rejects** those users who do not have access to that application.

However on a **successful login**, the user is redirected to the callback page (defined as the first callback in the Auth0 settings and the OIDCRedirectURI in `auth_openidc.conf`, e.g. `website.com/auth`) and **not** back to the application the user attempted to load.

**How do I configure Auth0 with Apache so that a user is returned to the URL of the application they initially attempted to load and not the callback URL?**

**Good**

- `website.com/app1 > AUTH0 login >  website.com/app1`
- `website.com/app2 > AUTH0 login >  website.com/app2`

**Bad**

- `website.com/app1 > AUTH0 login >  website.com/auth`

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with a few different approaches:

1. You can register more than one callback/redirect URL within the client application configuration in Auth0 and then each application starts the login process by telling Auth0 the redirect URL associated with it.
2. You can represent your applications as multiple client applications in Auth0 where each one has a specific callback redirect URL and each application starts the process with that redirect URL.
3. You can continue to use the same callback URL and then do a second redirect to the final destination. This implies knowing where the user started the process which can be achieved by leveraging OAuth state parameter (this parameter should also be used for CSRF protection, see [Using the State Parameter](https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/oauth2/oauth-state).

Options **1.** and **2.** are very similar, usually if we talking about conceptually different applications you would go with option **2** and if it's a single application that just wants to have two different ways of processing the callback you would go with option **1.**.

Finally, option **3** allows a similar thing to what's done in the first option, that is, the same application can conditionally redirect users to different places after login, but does it without the need to register additional redirect URL's in the Auth0 side. It's the application itself that decides where the user goes after processing the login at the callback URL.

Comment: Great answer thanks. In regards to **Option 1**, I have already registered multiple callback URLs in the Auth0 client application.  A 'master' redirect URI is set for the `OIDCRedirectURI` parameter in Apache's `auth_openidc.conf` which is used as the default redirect location. How do I specify the use of a second callback URL (registered with Auth0) that differs from `OIDCRedirectURI`?

Comment: I never used Apache OIDC module, but have you tried setting `OIDCRedirectURI` within each `location` primitive? It may allow you to override the default URI based on current application path.